# When I hit Enter in bash on AIX, command is not executed

Tags: bash, aix

I'm having an issue with an AIX 5.3 machine, the default shell is ksh and it behaves well, but I want to use bash in order to have bash completions and some syntax advantages it offers but whenever I type bash, when I want to run any command, when I hit Enter key it only makes a line break and my command is never executed, like if it is expecting a multiline text.

Here there are some file scripts in my home dir:

.profile

```
USER=`whoami`
export HOST USER
export PS1='$USER@$HOST:$PWD=> '
ENV="$HOME/.kshrc"
export ENV
export EXINIT='set nu ai sm'
```

.kshrc

```
set-o vi
alias dir='ls -ltr'
```

Example:

```
=> pwd
/
=> bash
$ pwd
```

What is wrong with my configuration that produces this behaviour?

Comment: Having an `ENV` written for ksh still exported when you run bash is not something I'd recommend. Not saying it's your problem, but it certainly won't help.

Comment: I'd also advise against exporting `PS1`. Just set it with no export in your `.kshrc`, and it won't try to be used on non-ksh shells.

Comment: Anyhow, `(unset ENV; exec bash -x -l -i)`, and you'll get a log of what's going on in your shell.

Comment: Thanks I was given this server and it already had this configuration, I tried the command but still got hung, is this log you're talking about inside a file I can look for?

Comment: Nope -- that's going to stderr. Presumably there were some lines printed with `+` before them when you ran the above, before it hung -- can you provide them, either in the question or at https://gist.github.com/ or another ad-free pastebin?

Comment: By the way, if bash expects multi-line text, it'll print a line continuation string -- by default, `> `.

Comment: Thanks, I added the complete output in this link: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4734ad78b1a0f1a1ae9e184a315fc6d4

Comment: No output when it hangs. And no `>` character on every new line

Comment: No output *at all* from `bash -x -l -i`? That's interesting -- it implies that the shell isn't even successfully running any init scripts (`.profile` and the like).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143421/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-javier-p).

Comment: Regarding compilation from source: if I am not completely mistaken, I have to download `https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4.tar.gz` and the twelve patches too: `wget --no-check-certificate $(seq -f "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches/bash44-%03g" 1 12)`

Comment: I admit, I was wrong when I said compiling bash-4.4 with gcc couldn't be harder than compiling bash-4.3 with gcc. The difference I didn't know of was plugins (even if they are dubbed as examples/loadables) -- shared modules _are_ different on AIX.

Comment: On the other hand, I could reproduce the problem with bash_64.rpm from perzl.org -- there is an infinite loop in it, but it is compiled without debug-symbols; also I haven't got xlc compiler, so I found out nothing.

Comment: stuck here too... did you do something to reproduce it besides just installing the package?